# Clarifications regarding Google Cloud Translate API's EU regional endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

We are adopting the new Standard Contractual Clauses (SCCs) by the EU Commission.

With respect to that, we need few clarifications regarding the Google Cloud Translation EU regional API endpoint that we're planning to use for our EU customers.

> 1. How long does Google store the data we send for translation if we use the EU API endpoint?
> 2. If the data is stored, for how long?
> 3. If the data is stored, is it encrypted in storage?
> 4. Do members/employees from other entities (eg. the USA) have access to this data? If yes, from which countries?

Please do look into this at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your questions:

> 1.- Based on this documentation[1] When you send text to Cloud Translation API, Google Cloud must store that text for a short period
> of time in order to perform the translation and return the results to
> you. The stored text is typically deleted after 7 days, but can be
> temporarily stored up to 14 days in the event of a service failure.
>
> 2.- The data will have the same storage rules (as the ones mentioned in the first answer), since Google Cloud Services are global.
>
> 3.- Google’s Security Measures. The Security Measures include measures to encrypt personal data; to help ensure ongoing
> confidentiality, integrity, availability and resilience of Google’s
> systems and services. You can see more information about these
> security measures in the following document [2] at section 7.
>
> 4.- Google Cloud Services are global so if you give them access through Google IAM to your data they can.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/translate/data-usage

[2] https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms